# Does std::ofstream::trunc delete content if it can't open file?

Tags: c++

As the question says, I am curios to know what happens if `file.open(filePath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);` doesn't open the respective file.

Will it delete its content even if it won't open it ?

Comment: how should it modify the file contents without opening the file?

Comment: @bleah1 The content of a file can not be deleted if there is no access to the file.:)

Comment: That seems fair and correct ! I wanted to make sure, despite all the logic behind it.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

No, an unopened file cannot be modified.